# How do I update Ubuntu manually?

Tags: updates

I wanted to update Ubuntu manually, because I used CDMA USB modem and connected using `wvdial`, but it won't able to update Ubuntu via Update Manager, because my Ubuntu won't showing "Connected" message via `network-manager`.

Can I update Ubuntu manually? Am I should download separate files, or use terminal instead?

Comment: All answers seems similar. I'll try when I connected on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can manually update via terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Additionally you can run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

From the `apt-get` manpage:

> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also
>   intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of
>   packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it
>   will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of
>   less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may
>   therefore remove some packages.

Comment: Which one? `update` or `upgrade`? Because I think both of them is different

Comment: Why not `dist-upgrade`? A regular `upgrade` could hold back some stuff. (It won't upgrade the Ubuntu version unless you alter your sources, though.)

Comment: My Ubuntu version is [tag:13.04] Is that need `dist-upgrade`? Or not?

Comment: @AryoAdhi You need both. `update` will update the package lists (to be able to tell what packages are available) and `upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` will perform the actual updating.

Comment: @AryoAdhi `upgrade` upgrades only the already installed packages. `dist-upgrade` upgrades packages AND also install/remove packages if some package dependency list has changed. If you run `apt-get dist-upgrade` make sure to review the changes apt-get will perform before confirming the operation. `dist-upgrade` will NOT upgrade Ubuntu version (e.g. 12.10 -> 13.04).

Comment: Note that this answer here requires an internet connection.  If they don't have an internet connection they can't update the packages.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` will upgrade to a newer major version (12 => 14).

Answer (score 11):

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in a terminal. Re-boot if it asks.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade the Ubuntu version (eg... 12.04 to 12.10 or 13.04) you can just pop in the LiveCD/LiveUSB and it has an option to allow you to upgrade.

Comment: *"much safer than an Internet connection"* How would this be safer than using an internet connection? Besides, the released ISOs contain an older non-updated set of packages after the release (well, LTS has point-releases). So I'd say, updating using the internet is essentially safer, because you'll get the latest security patches as well.

Comment: Yes, Security-wise it is, but as for running the risk of having your internet cut out on you in the middle of a crucial file could be pretty disastrous. And, once you upgrade via that device, you can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure you have the latest updates.

Comment: *"having your internet cut out on you in the middle of a crucial file could be pretty disastrous"* No. Because it will first download before processing the updates. *"once you upgrade via that device, you can run [...]"* That will run updates of packages upgraded in the step before, exactly my point of being inefficient.