# Will apt-get upgrade upgrade all my installed software?

Tags: apt, updates

This question is probably already asked but I could not find clear answer. I am using Lubuntu 13. 10. How do I fully update via terminal? I do:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Will these commands update my whole system? If I download an outdated app, will it be updated from these commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update Ubuntu manually?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301484/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-manually)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes the above will upgrade all installed packages including any installed using `apt-get` but not any you installed by compiling from source.

[How do I update Ubuntu manually?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301484/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-manually)

Comment: I dont understand the : but not any you have installed by compiling from source.

Comment: @user226755 If you don't understand what that means don't worry, you haven't (compiled any from source). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: So it wont update programs that are not "signed" ?

Comment: I installed Skype , using the package from the official page, will it update yes or no?

Comment: @theowner997 It has nothing to do with signing. Some Unix and Linux users opt to compile programs from source code. Don't worry about it. If you really want to understand what that means you can follow the link I provided. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo