# USB mouse not detected after software update

Tags: usb, mouse

On Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop, I'm having trouble with my USB mouse. I did a software update this morning and it appears to have broken some things. My USB optical mouse is not being detected (the light comes on but the computer isn't detecting the mouse; I've tried this in two different USB ports with two different mice).

`xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
9: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" [XExtensionPointer]
10: "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" [XExtensionPointer]`

Really not sure what I can do to fix this. The computer also can't detect wifi after the update, if that is at all related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my own problem

I did a [manual software update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301484/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-manually) and that solved the problem (11/10/2015)