# I can't launch Scene Builder

Tags: command-line, 17.04, javafx

I recently started JAVAFX, so I got SceneBuilder to help... but I can't it launch after installation and reinstallation.

It prints

> segmentation fault (core dumped)

as an error when I try to run it via the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem last few days and few minutes ago I got solution from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301484/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-manually) and it worked perfectly (if you are ubuntu user).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Edit:**

when the installation is complete the prompt for restart will appear do it. If the prompt don't appear then you have to do it manually by

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: it did not work